# Concise way to create an array of values not found in a complex nested objects and arrays

Tags: javascript

What would a concise way of creating an array of ids where none of the values of the key "number" in array "numbers" in any object of the mainArray array equal the string number 33333. I know i could create a for loop, but I'm curious if theres a more simple way to do this.

```
var mainArray = [
    {   
        id:"1",
        "numbers":[
            {number:"11111"},
            {number:"22222"},
        ]
    },
    {   
        id:"2",
        "numbers":[
            {number:"33333"},
            {number:"44444"},
        ]
    },
    {   
        id:"3",
        "numbers":[
            {number:"55555"},
            {number:"66666"},
        ]
    },
]
```

Answer should be

```
["1","3"]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First filter the array by checking that the `numbers` subarray contains no matching values with `.some`, then map to the IDs.

```js
var mainArray = [
    {   
        id:"1",
        "numbers":[
            {number:"11111"},
            {number:"22222"},
        ]
    },
    {   
        id:"2",
        "numbers":[
            {number:"33333"},
            {number:"44444"},
        ]
    },
    {   
        id:"3",
        "numbers":[
            {number:"55555"},
            {number:"66666"},
        ]
    },
]

const output = mainArray
  .filter(obj => !obj.numbers.some(({ number }) => number === '33333'))
  .map(({ id }) => id);
console.log(output);
```

Comment: An alternative to `!some` is *every*: `obj.numbers.every(({ number }) => number !== '33333')`. There is a [draft proposal for an *omit* method](https://github.com/aleen42/proposal-object-pick-or-omit) that would be more semantic. :-)

Comment: @polar I see that you often miss marking the useful answer as resolved by clicking the tick.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers